# Помогите исправить ошибку 'not a statement'

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class FloydTriangle {
 public static void main(String[] args){

    int range, i, j, k=1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the num of rows: ");
    range=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Floyd's Triangle :\n");
    for(i=1; i<=range; i++)
    {
        for(j=1, j<=i; j++; k++)
        {
            System.out.println(k + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Следующий код при компиляции выдает ошибку: Error:(15, 23) java: not a statement в этой строке: for(j=1, j<=i; j++; k++)

Comment: Вместо запятой поставь точку с запятой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый for написали правильно, а второй нет. Вместо `,` нужно `;`.

```
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++, k++)
        {
            System.out.println(k + " ");
        }
```

Comment: Вы написали не валидный код для Java, правильно будет:  for(j=1; j<=i; j++, k++)

Comment: @JavaJunior поправил